# Find all $\alpha$ such that integral converges

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, taylor-expansion

Find all $\alpha$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{e^2+x^2} - e^{\cos x}}{x^{\alpha}}$ converges. Can you give me a hint how to start? I have an idea to change smth with Taylor series, but is it alright to say,  i.e 
$e^{\cos x}$ ~ $e - \frac{ex^2}{2}$ in this integral?

Answer (score 1):

Applying L'Hopital's Rule twice you get $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac {\sqrt {e^{2}+x^{2}} -e^{\cos\, x}} {x^{2}}=\frac {e+1/e} 2$. The integral converges iff $\alpha <3$.